# PHP as a bridge to an smtp/pop3 server

Tags: php, email, smtp, pop3

Is it possible if I want to use PHP script to be used as the bridge or the middle man from the clients to the real smtp/pop3 server? The real server is behind a firewall and will not be configured to be accessible for the public. So I need a fake server which just relay the email to the real smtp server. Is it possible to be done?

Comment: Does it *have* to be PHP? I imagine there are much more suitable solutions for this.

Comment: It's hosted by godaddy. Not much can be done about that. But I'd love to hear any other possible solution too. Thanks.

Comment: Thx Tomalak :D That's an eye opener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure it is fundamentally impossible to have a PHP script on shared hosting perform the functions of a true POP3 / SMTP proxy.

The requests coming from the clients would be using those protocols, and try to connect to your Godaddy server. That server will either have its own POP3 / SMTP server listening on those ports, or none.

You would have to use a server on which you have full root privileges to do this - but then, you will no longer need PHP, there will be better tools to do that available to you there.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you could write a proxy, you'd have to implement the wire-level SMTP / POP3 / IMAP protocols in PHP.  This would have to be run a a service (i.e. CLI, not inside Apache).  If you need a mail proxy, have you considered nginx?